# Update query Codeigniter Message

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am running update query to update  book record in library. Now problem is, how to print success message after update success instead of update success? 
After updating it is redirecting on blank page.

My model is

```
function update_book($data, $id)
{
  $this->load->database();
  $this->db->where("id", $id);
  $query =$this->db->update("books", $data);

  if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0)
  {
    $response = array(
           'message' => "User edited successfully",
           'status' => true
           );
  }
  else
    $response = array(
         'message' => "There is nothing to update",
         'status' => false
        );

  return $response;
}
```

and Controller is:

```
public function edit_info()
{
  $id = $this->input->post('id');
  $book_name = $this->input->post('book_name');
  $book_author = $this->input->post('book_author');
  $book_publisher = $this->input->post('book_publisher');
  $book_pages = $this->input->post('book_pages');
  $book_price = $this->input->post('book_price');
  $book_stock = $this->input->post('book_stock');

  $book_data = array(  
            'id'=>$id,
            'book_name'=>$book_name,
            'book_author'=>$book_author,
            'book_publisher'=>$book_publisher,
            'book_pages'=>$book_pages,
            'book_price'=>$book_price,
            'book_stock'=>$book_stock
          );

  $this->load->model('Book');
  $result = $this->Book->update_book($book_data, $id);

  if(in_array(1, $result))
  {
    $this->session->set_flash-data('MSG', 'Book Record Updated!!');
  }
  else
  {
    echo "FALSE";
  }
}
```

Comment: Please tell us your error, your question is not clear

Answer (score 1):

```
if($result['status'] == true){
    echo $result['message'];
    $this->session->set_flashdata('MSG', 'Book Record Updated!!');
}
else{
    echo $result['message'];
}
```

In your redirect blanck page `echo $this->session->flashdata('MSG');`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

**Model**

```
function update_book($data, $id)
{
  $this->load->database();
  $this->db->where("id", $id)
  return $this->db->update("books", $data);
}
```

**Controller**

```
 $this->load->model('Book');
 $result = $this->Book->update_book($book_data, $id);
 if($result){

     $response = array(
       'message' => "User edited successfully",
       'status' => true
       );
  }else{

     $response = array(
     'message' => "There is nothing to update",
     'status' => false
    );
  }
```